# SwiftUI "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass" for UIViewRepresentable

Tags: swiftui

I am using a UIViewRepresentable view in my SwiftUI app to make a video player play inside of a SwiftUI view.

I need to pass a resource String to the video player so it plays the correct video instead of a hard-coded value defined in the PlayerUIView.

The error I am getting is **Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass** when adding *videoResource: String* to the *override init* inside of the PlayerUIView class.

I am not used to working with **override init()** so I don't know why I can't initialize properties like a normal initializer??

Everything works perfectly if I hard code the video string inside of PlayerUIView and *remove videoResource: String from the override init()* but I don't know why I can't pass the override init() a value??

What am I doing wrong?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VideoPlayerView(resource: "video-name")
    }
}
```

```
struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let resource: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return PlayerUIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), videoResource: resource)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {  }
}
```

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView {
      
    private var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?

    // ERROR -> "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass"
    override init(frame: CGRect, videoResource: String) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoResource, withExtension: "mp4")!
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL)

        let player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: playerItem)

        player.play()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder: ) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `override` here. That is used to implement a method that is implemented in the superclass, and the superclass doesn't have that init. The correct declaration would be (removing the `override`):

```
init(frame: CGRect, videoResource: String) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to update the player, e.g.

```
   let resource: String

   ...

   func updateUIView(_ uiView: PlayerUIView, context: Context) {  
       uiView.resource = resource
   }
```